# Insert video into someone else's playlist YouTube API v3 results in 403

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I'm trying to insert a video into someone else's playlist (I'm a collaborator). I can insert the video from youtube.com (website), but doing it via the YouTube API V3 gives a 403.

Response:

> {  "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
>       "reason": "playlistItemsNotAccessible",
>       "message": "Forbidden"    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Forbidden"  } }

For the playlists that I own, the youtube api works fine.

Any clue how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The [error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#playlistItems_youtube.playlistItems.insert) indicates that the request made was not properly authorized to insert the specified playlist item

> forbidden (403) `playlistItemsNotAccessible`  The request is not properly authorized to insert the specified playlist item.

You can insert a playlist item in your account since you're using it the account authorized by the API. Since you're trying it on a different account, its resulting with the 403 error. I don't know how its possible in the youtube website, though.

Comment: Yup. Thing is I am added as a collaborator in that playlist, so I should have permissions to add to that playlist (and I can do so from the web because of the same reason, that I'm a collaborator). I couldn't find any specific permissions or settings related to collaboration when it comes to the youtube API .

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm also wondering about this. There doesn't seem to be a way to determine whether a user is allowed to edit a playlist